Android notification - set default timeout
I am using my Android phone (running Android 14 - API34) to test an app which builds a notification. My problem is that the notification disappears after a few seconds (leaving just a notification dot) and I need it to stay on screen for maybe two minutes.
The phone settings option "Settings - Accessibility - Timing Controls - Time to take action" allows me to change the default timeout for my phone. However, I don't want the user to have to do this - I want my app to override the default timeout and make the notification stay on the screen for longer.
I have put setOngoing(true) and setTimeoutAfter(120000) in my java code:
    void createPopUpNotification(int nfNo){
            if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID;
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "AMJnotifychannel";
                Intent goShow = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
                goShow.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, goShow, FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
                RemoteViews expandedView=new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.expandednotify);
                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.placename,placeName);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE ) ;
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "amjchannel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                    channel.shouldVibrate();
                    channel.enableLights(true);
                    channel.enableVibration(true);
                    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.amjnotify);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                builder.setCustomContentView(expandedView);
                builder.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);
                builder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                builder.setOngoing(true);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setTimeoutAfter(120000);
                builder.setChannelId( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ) ;
                notificationManager.notify(nfNo, builder.build());
            }
        }
  

but it doesn't override the devices's standard timeout. The notification still disappears after a few seconds if I set the "Time to take action" setting to default on the phone.
Can anyone suggest a way of making my app override the phone's default timeout for the notification?

What do you mean by "the notification disappears"? Do you mean that you are getting a heads-up notification (based on your other settings), and you want that heads-up popover to appear for minutes?

Yes ( think so - you probably realise that I am not an Android expert!) - or I want some other way of achieving the same kind of thing

Are you building your own hardware with your own build of the Android OS on it? If so, you should be able to adjust the duration of a heads-up notification by modifying the OS.

No. It is an app for anyone to use on standard devices

Then I strongly suspect that what you seek will not be an option.

Great! That makes the app rather useless! I'll have to think of some other way around it. Thanks for your help
